# Blender on Surface Pro X

Tags: performance

Blender will not work on the Surface Pro X. It runs, but it doesn't recognize the GPU in the machine and shuts itself down. All my drivers and firmware are up to date.

The GPU should be more than capable since it's quite powerful and has dedicated memory. The CPU is questionable, but that's beside the point. Is there a work around or another build of Blender I could use? If not, would it be possible to get this compatibility in a future update?

Comment: You can test if it works properly with the [2.82 alpha](https://builder.blender.org/download/). If it doesn't, this question is best asked on https://blender.chat/ and *if* one of our GPU experts confirms that the hardware should be supported, then you could file a bug report.